# Building an unordered list from multiple MySQL tables

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, html-lists

I am trying to build a menu populated with categories, subcategories and tertiary categories that are stored in three separate tables in database as follows:

```
TABLE A
------------------------
| ID | name            |
| 1  | Category 1      |
| 2  | Category 2      |
------------------------

TABLE B
------------------------------------
| ID | Parent_ID | name_b          |
| 1  |     1     | Subcategory 1   |
| 2  |     1     | Subcategory 2   |
| 3  |     2     | Subcategory 3   |
------------------------------------

TABLE C
--------------------------------------
| ID | Parent_ID | name_c             |
| 1  |     1     | Tertiarycategory 1 |
| 2  |     2     | Tertiarycategory 2 |
| 3  |     2     | Tertiarycategory 3 |
| 4  |     3     | Tertiarycategory 4 |
--------------------------------------
```

These should be returned in an unordered list looking someting like

- Category 1

  - Subcategory 1

    - Tertiarycategory 1
  - Subcategory 2

    - Tertiarycategory 2
    - Tertiarycategory 3
- Category 2

  - Subcategory 3

    - Tertiarycategory 4

I've been googling for a couple days now trying out diffrent stuff, but cannot seem to get it working, so would very much appreciate it if someone could crack it for me :)

Tried this to get first and second levels (without the listing, just normal echo while I get the queries right) but it did not work at all...

```
    $query_select = "SELECT * FROM table_a";
$result_select = mysqli_query($link, $query_select) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($menurow = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select))
$menurows[] = $menurow;
foreach($menurows as $menurow){ 
$ename = stripslashes($menurow['name']);
$eid = $menurow['id'];
echo $ename . '<br/>';
        $query_select2 = "SELECT * FROM table_b WHERE parent_id = '$eid'";
        $result_select2 = mysqli_query($link, $query_select2) or die(mysql_error());
        $rows2 = array();
        while($menurow2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select2))
        $menurows2[] = $menurow2;
        foreach($menurows2 as $menurow2){ 
        $ename2 = stripslashes($menurow2['name_b']);
        $eid2 = $menurow2['id'];
        echo $ename2 . '<br/>';

}
```

}

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: I would join on the database to return a single result-set (but in order) and then walk that into the tables in a loop that focuses on category id/name changes.

Comment: I have tried to figure out JOINs but get no result at all, I have tried multiple queries but cannot figure it out.

Thing is.... I'm mostly a designer, and my PHP/MySQL skills are limited at best, and rusty on top of that. If someone wants to write down the neccessary code to get this working I would love thm long time (and by studying said code be able to understand how to do this for future needs)

Comment: You can do a query to get the first level, and for each of them echo the categorie name and query for the second level, and for each of these second level, do the same : echo the subcategory and query for the third level. Finally, for each third level, echo the tertiarycategory. Not the most optimized but quite simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just use a simple join to get all the parent / child relationships, and sort out the output of the top level parents in code when they change (this would be easy in php).

```
SELECT name, name_b, name_c
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.ID = B.Parent_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN C
ON B.ID = C.Parent_ID
ORDER BY A.ID, B.ID, C.ID
```

EDIT

PHP script to take the details from the table and build the unordered lists.

This uses a small class to output each unordered list, closing it in the destructor. Then it creates an instance of this class for each level of unordered list.

```
<?php

#------ database connections -------
define('MYSQLHOST','localhost');
define('MYSQLUSER','root');
define('MYSQLPASS','');
define('MYSQLDATABASE','tests');

$link = mysqli_connect(MYSQLHOST, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDATABASE);

$prev_name = '';
$prev_name_b = '';
$prev_name_c = '';

$query_select = "SELECT name, name_b, name_c
                FROM A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN B
                ON A.ID = B.Parent_ID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN C
                ON B.ID = C.Parent_ID
                ORDER BY A.ID, B.ID, C.ID";

$result_select = mysqli_query($link, $query_select) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();
while($menurow = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select))
{
    if ($menurow['name'] != $prev_name)
    {
        if (isset($name_c_object)) unset($name_c_object);
        if (isset($name_b_object)) unset($name_b_object);
        if (isset($name_object)) unset($name_object);
        $name_object = new ul(1);
        $prev_name = $menurow['name'];
        $name_object->li($prev_name);
    }
    if ($menurow['name_b'] != $prev_name_b)
    {
        if (isset($name_c_object)) unset($name_c_object);
        if (isset($name_b_object)) unset($name_b_object);
        $name_b_object = new ul(3);
        $prev_name_b = $menurow['name_b'];
        $name_b_object->li($prev_name_b);
        if (isset($name_c_object)) unset($name_c_object);
        $name_c_object = new ul(5);
    }
    $name_c_object->li($menurow['name_c']);
}

if (isset($name_c_object)) unset($name_c_object);
if (isset($name_b_object)) unset($name_b_object);
if (isset($name_object)) unset($name_object);

class ul
{
    private $out_li = false;
    private $num_tab = 0;
    public function __CONSTRUCT($num_tab)
    {
        $this->num_tab = $num_tab;
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."<ul>\r\n";
    }
    public function __DESTRUCT()
    {
        if ($this->out_li) echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t</li>\r\n";
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."</ul>\r\n";
    }
    public function li($li)
    {
        if ($this->out_li) echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t</li>\r\n";
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t<li>\r\n";
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t\t$li\r\n";
        $this->out_li = true;
    }
}
```

EDIT again

I have had a rethink and got my head around it:-

```
<?php

#------ database connections -------
define('MYSQLHOST','localhost');
define('MYSQLUSER','root');
define('MYSQLPASS','');
define('MYSQLDATABASE','tests');

$link = mysqli_connect(MYSQLHOST, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDATABASE);

$prev_id_a = 0;
$prev_id_b = 0;
$prev_id_c = 0;

$query_select = "SELECT name, name_b, name_c, A.ID AS aid, B.ID AS bid, C.ID AS cid
                FROM A
                LEFT OUTER JOIN B
                ON A.ID = B.Parent_ID
                LEFT OUTER JOIN C
                ON B.ID = C.Parent_ID
                ORDER BY A.ID, B.ID, C.ID";

$result_select = mysqli_query($link, $query_select) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = array();

$name_a_object = new ul(0);

while($menurow = mysqli_fetch_array($result_select))
{
    if ($menurow['aid'] != $prev_id_a)
    {
        if (isset($name_c_object)) unset($name_c_object);
        if (isset($name_b_object)) unset($name_b_object);
        $name_a_object->li($menurow['name']);
        $name_b_object = new ul(2);
        $prev_id_a = $menurow['aid'];
    }
    if ($menurow['bid'] != $prev_id_b)
    {
        if (isset($name_c_object)) unset($name_c_object);
        $name_b_object->li($menurow['name_b']);
        $name_c_object = new ul(4);
        $prev_id_b = $menurow['bid'];
    }
    $name_c_object->li($menurow['name_c']);
}

if (isset($name_c_object)) unset($name_c_object);
if (isset($name_b_object)) unset($name_b_object);
if (isset($name_a_object)) unset($name_a_object);

class ul
{
    private $num_tab = 0;
    private $li_output = false;
    public function __CONSTRUCT($num_tab, $li=null)
    {
        $this->num_tab = $num_tab;
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."<ul>\r\n";
        if ($li != null)
        {
            echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t<li>\r\n";
            echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t\t$li\r\n";
        }
    }
    public function __DESTRUCT()
    {
        if ($this->li_output)
        {
            echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t</li>\r\n";
        }
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."</ul>\r\n";
    }
    public function li($li)
    {
        if ($this->li_output)
        {
            echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t</li>\r\n";
        }
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t<li>\r\n";
        echo str_repeat("\t", $this->num_tab)."\t\t$li\r\n";
        $this->li_output = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am still not sure how to output this though, but will try to figure it out :)

Comment: Updated with a simple php script to output the lists. As this just uses a single SQL query this should be fairly efficient. It would be better if tweaked to check for changes in the id, but I was getting lazy.

Comment: Thank you! That is a huge step forward. There is a minor issue, that on the second and third tier, every entry is placed in a separate <ul> rather than a single one (there should be one <UL> with all second tier entries, and one around all third tier entries if that makes sense...). Trying to find the cause. Everything else is working beautifully :)

Comment: For each tier change it generates a new unordered list. I can modify it to avoid that if you want. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: Modified - just changed it so it instantiates the object for the last tier when it detects a change in the middle tier.

Comment: Where is this modification made? Just need to do the same to second tier, and we should be across the finish-line :)

Output should be
` <ul>
  <li>tier1
   <ul>
             <li>tier2
     <ul>
      <li>tier3</li>
      <li>tier3</li>
      <li>tier3</li>
     </ul>   
    </li>
    <li>tier2
     <ul>
      <li>tier3</li>
      <li>tier3</li>
      <li>tier3</li>
     </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>`

Comment: The mod was removing the last IF block and putting a change in the previous IF block. Probably easiest for you to click the link above saying when the post was edited and it will show you the changes made.

Comment: Thanks. Tried copying what you had done, but looks like I made more of a mess than progress :p

Comment: Yea, the code works beautifully. There is only the minor detail of every second tier result ending up in a separate <ul> like it was on the third before change. There should be one main <UL> for the menu as a whole with first tier results in <li></li> then inside each of these <li> there should be another <ul> with second tier as <li></li> and then lastly a third <ul> nested into these with third tier results as <li></li> like it is now.

Comment: For clarity I've tried to illustrate with just HTML: http://pastebin.com/82DrGFjV

Visually when just viewing it as an unordered list, the two look identical, but the extra <ul> tags mess with the CSS styling

Comment: I have had an extra think to get my head around it. I think I have it now (but if not paste up a bit of test data to demonstrate it please).

Comment: Great success! Thank you very very much! Now it's just a matter of styling it with CSS, something I am far more comfortable with :)

Answer (score 1):

All queries returns data in one dimension. But you can have workaround like this:

```
SELECT x.level,x.id,x.name
FROM
(
  SELECT 1 as level, id as id, name as name
    , id as id_1,-1 as id_2, -1 as id_3
    FROM table_a
    WHERE 1
  UNION
  SELECT 2 as level, id as id, name_b as name
    , Parent_ID as id_1,id as id_2, -1 as id_3
    FROM table_b
    WHERE 1
  UNION
  SELECT 3 as level, c.id as id, c.name_c as name
    , b.Parent_ID as id_1,b.id as id_2, c.id as id_3
    FROM table_c c LEFT JOIN table_b b ON c.Parent_ID=b.id
    WHERE 1
) x
WHERE 1
ORDER BY id_1,id_2,id_3
```

that should return

```
Level | Name
1       Category 1
2       Subcategory 1
3       Tertiarycategory 1
2       Subcategory 2
3       Tertiarycategory 2
3       Tertiarycategory 3
1       Category 2
2       Subcategory 3
3       Tertiarycategory 4
```

and PHP code is:

```
$r = $db->query($query);
$level = 0;
while($x=mysql_fetch_object($r))
{
   while($level < $x->level)
   {
      echo '<ul>';
      $level++;
   }
   while($level > $x->level)
   {
      echo '</ul>';
      $level--;
   }
   echo '<li>'$x->ID.'#'.$x->name;
} 
while($level-- > 0)
   echo '</ul>';
```

---

**edit:** Or, instead of leaving the building work to MySQL, let's do it simply inside PHP

```
$r1 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_a order by ID");
$r2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_b order by Parent_ID");
$r3 = $db->query("SELECT table_c.* 
                  FROM table_c
                  LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_c.Parent_ID=table_b.ID
                  order by table_b.Parent_ID");

$e1 = mysql_fetch_object($r1);
$e2 = mysql_fetch_object($r2);
$e3 = mysql_fetch_object($r3);

echo "<ul>";
while($e1)
{
   echo "<li>".htmlentities($e1->name);
   if($e2 && $e2->Parent_ID==$e1->ID)
   {
      echo "<ul>";
      while($e2 && $e2->Parent_ID==$e1->ID)
      {
         echo "<li>".htmlentities($e2->name_b);
         if($e3 && $e3->Parent_ID==$e2->ID)
         {
            echo "<ul>";
            while($e3 && $e3->Parent_ID==$e2->ID)
            {
               echo "<li>".htmlentities($e3->name_3);
               $e3 = mysql_fetch_object($r3);
            }
            echo "</ul>";
         }
         $e2 = mysql_fetch_object($r2);
      }
      echo "</ul>";
   }
   $e1 = mysql_fetch_object($r1);
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Will see if this gets me any further

Comment: Tried it out but no results are returned. Could I bother you to post a complete script with DB connection etc so I can see where I am messing it up?

Comment: If you need to ask for 'including DB connection', then first, go there: https://www.google.com/search?q=php+mysqli+basics

Comment: I'll add an aswer to get while code as it is now, without giving any returns

Comment: On your first snippet, you added `level` to the database or is `level` the `parent_id`? I hope you can answer me on this old question!

Comment: @Alex As you can see, it is created inside subquery like `SELECT 1 as level, ...` It is essetially 3 mysql queries in one with added constant to diferentiate them.

Comment: @David162795 Thank you for your answer, it makes more sense now but I have a problem, when I run this script it keeps looping, so the unordered list keeps repeating it's self, any clue? I can open a question and put the link here?

Comment: The query in phpMyAdmin just shows the table/list once, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got it, needed to change a `while` to `if`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code currently, but no results are returned.

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; //server
$db = "xx"; //database name
$user = "xx"; //dabases user name
$pwd = "xx"; //password

//connecting to server and creating link to database
$dblink = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $db);

$r1 = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM auction_a_categories order by ID");
$r2 = $dblink->query("SELECT * FROM auction_b_categories order by Parent_ID");
$r3 = $dblink->query("SELECT auction_c_categories.* 
                  FROM auction_c_categories
                  LEFT JOIN auction_b_categories ON auction_c_categories.Parent_ID=auction_b_categories.ID
                  order by auction_b_categories.Parent_ID");

$e1 = mysql_fetch_object($r1);
$e2 = mysql_fetch_object($r2);
$e3 = mysql_fetch_object($r3);

echo "<ul>";
while($e1)
{
   echo "<li>".htmlentities($e1->name);
   if($e2 && $e2->Parent_ID==$e1->ID)
   {
      echo "<ul>";
      while($e2 && $e2->Parent_ID==$e1->ID)
      {
         echo "<li>".htmlentities($e2->name_b);
         if($e3 && $e3->Parent_ID==$e2->ID)
         {
            echo "<ul>";
            while($e3 && $e3->Parent_ID==$e2->ID)
            {
               echo "<li>".htmlentities($e3->name_3);
               $e3 = mysql_fetch_object($r3);
            }
            echo "</ul>";
         }
         $e2 = mysql_fetch_object($r2);
      }
      echo "</ul>";
   }
   $e1 = mysql_fetch_object($r1);
}
echo "</ul>";

?>
```